# How do I add the domain I own in oracle cloud and host it live?

Tags: web-hosting, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to upload my local wordpress to the domain I bought and make it live. But I don't know how to add domain and add dns in oracle cloud.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no simple answer to your question. The general documentation on using Oracle Cloud DNS Service can be found [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/DNS/Tasks/managingdnszones.htm#Using). Below is a quick summary of tasks that need to be completed:

1. Note the public IP address assigned to your compute instance that's hosting the web server. Assign one if necessary. The compute instance must be on a public subnet to be assigned one.
2. In your tenant's root compartment, create a Zone for your domain, e.g. example.com.
3. Create an "A" zone record, e.g. www.example.com => 123.123.123.123
4. Publish the record.
5. On your Registrar's DNS management console, update the name server records to point to Oracle Cloud's name servers assigned to the zone.